# JPA configure boolean fields to persist as integers

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA is there an annotation to specify that boolean fields should be persisted as an integer.
I'm using OpenJPA and it's currently persisting boolean fields as bits. I'd rather use integer 1 or 0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify the column definition:

```
@Column(name="boolColumn",
     columnDefinition="INT(1)")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following annotation:

```
@Type(type="numeric_boolean")
```

If you want to write Y and N instead of 0, 1, you can use

```
@Type(type="yes_no")
```

Comment: Nice tip! But beware this is Hibernate specific, not standard JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Three more years later, in Hibernate 6, use

```
@Convert(converter = NumericBooleanConverter.class)
public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return this.enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with the question, a long time later, but very related but for Hibernate 4.3.7 higher, you can use

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
@Column(name="enabled1", nullable=false)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")  
public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return this.enabled;
}
```

As indicated in [enter link description here](https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-smallint-tinyint-int-column-to-boolean)

This has been tested in a migration from PostgreSQL to Oracle to avoid impact on JPA entities